# How does nohup work?

Tags: signals, nohup

My understanding is that in order to block a process signal like `SIGHUP`, you would need to do so from within the process the signal is being sent to.  Yet, a Unix shell like `bash` can spawn a child process and block the `HUP` signal for the child from within the parent, using the `nohup` command.  How does this work?  Does `nohup` block the signal and then exec the child process without forking?  That's the only way I can think of.

Answer (score 11):

You can take a look at the source code of an implementation of `nohup`, *e.g.* GNU's [`coreutils` version](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/nohup.c). There's a ton of setup, some of it for internationalisation purposes, the rest to handle the various redirection options; then the actual "nohupping" happens:

```
  signal (SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);

  char **cmd = argv + optind;
  execvp (*cmd, cmd);
```

As you surmise, this sets the process up to ignore the HUP signal, then `exec`s the requested command.

Comment: Does that mean that child process inherits signal handler SIG_IGN from parent process? In the end it's the child process that does not exit on SIGHUP, not the `nohup` process. That was the question.

Comment: Maybe this is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14852834/815741. It says (in the comment): "The only thing special about signals is that non-default, non-ignore handlers are reset on execve & friends (because the handler's address makes no sense in a new executable), but nothing like this happens on fork"

Comment: @VytenisBivainis there’s no child process here, the signal handling is configured in the same process as the “nohupped” command – note the absence of `fork` between the calls to `signal` and `exec`. Ignored signals are preserved across `exec`, and `SIGHUP` is ignored here.

Comment: As to what the question was, it’s spelt out in the question: “Does `nohup` block the signal and then exec the child process without forking?” That’s exactly what happens.

Comment: There is `/usr/bin/nohup` executable, but there is no process with that name. How can that be?

Comment: @Vytenis `nohup` replaces itself with whatever it’s asked to run. Once it’s set the redirections up, and ignored `SIGHUP`, it has nothing to do apart from executing the command it’s been given; so it does that, without forking, and the kernel replaces it with the new executable, in the same process. As a result you won’t see `nohup` in `ps`’s output for example, just the command `nohup` has set up.

Comment: Yeah, i see, thanks. "The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image" - from https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp. https://gist.github.com/kohsuke/0eeb9bb43ca8d62643dd#file-nohup-c-L226. I wonder how is memory managed in such cases. It seems that some part of memory taken before "replacement" remains, otherwise where is the signal handler persisted? And if it pointed to a normal function from previous image it must remain in memory even though the imaged is "replaced". If I understand correctly replace means "remove old, add new".

Comment: @Vytenis memory isn’t persisted. That’s why signal *handlers* are reset to the default, along with alternate signal stacks. In this case, `SIGHUP` is *ignored*, not handled; that’s what’s preserved.

Comment: Where is the fact that it is ignored persisted if not in memory (you say memory isn't persisted)?

Comment: @Vytenis in the process attributes which are [maintained by the kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.5/source/include/linux/sched.h#L985).

Comment: @StephenKitt Is `SIGHUP` the only signal ignored by the command run with `nohup` ?

Comment: @SebMa that depends on the command. The only change `nohup` makes to signal settings is to ignore `SIGHUP`, but other signals are ignored by default, and the command run with `nohup` can do its own signal setup too.

Answer (score 0):

The act of using `nohup` simply changes the PPID of the spawned process to 1 (init) so that when the shell exits, it is no longer a child process of that shell and so therefor doesn't receive a HUP.

EDIT: Should think more before I post sometimes. Leaving it here to remind me of my shame :-(